# Change selected TabItem height

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs

I'm using TabLayout and I'm looking for a way to change the height of the selected TabItem, so this one would be bigger than the others. I tried to use TabIndicator for that matter, but I can only change its color and size, not its position (it is always inside the TabLayout, and I would need to place it right on top of it to achieve the effect I need).

Is there a way to achieve this using selector, or in the layout xml itself?

Below is an example of the desired effect (the left one is the selected tab):

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/nav_item_color_state">
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tab 1"/>
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tab 2"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try to use `android:clipChildren="false"` on your TabLayout, and change the height programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two buttons and creating two different drawables to use as selected/unselected state in their backgrounds. Not elegant at all, but it worked.